# When I read in a Pandas Series from CSV it is turning it into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I create a pandas Series, I then output it to a CSV file. Then I try to open that CSV file in another worksheet using pandas.read_csv. I then check the type and it is now showing it as a DataFrame object??

I tried to fix it using-

```
series = df.transpose()[0]
```

and

```
df.ix[0]
```

but this did not work for me.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Here is an example of my problem-

I output my series to CSV and the CSV sheet then looks like this-

```
a,2
b,4
c,6
d,8
e,10
```

I then read the CSV into another worksheet using pd.read_csv(" ").
When I print this out here is what shows up-

```
   a  2
0  b  4
1  c  6
2  d  8
3  e  10
```

it is now a dataframe, and it now has columns "a" and "2", I can do header=None when reading the CSV to get rid of the columns...but the index is still 0,1,2,3 and its a dataframe.

Comment: gives me a KeyError:0

Comment: Where have these integers come from in the 2nd column of the output CSV file?

Comment: Try `pd.read_csv("my file", header=None, index_col=0).ix[:, 0]`.

Comment: still getting KeyError: 0, thanks for the effort, problem solved by John Zwinck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass [this option to `read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> squeeze : boolean, default False
>
> If the parsed data only contains one column then return a Series

Edit: Given the additional details you added, the full command you want is:

```
pd.read_csv('foo.txt', header=None, squeeze=True, index_col=0)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I did pd.read_csv("my file", squeeze="boolean") but it still is showing it as a DataFrame?

Comment: You need to pass `pd.read_csv("my file", squeeze=True)` instead

Comment: still says DataFrame, when I look at the info on the CSV it looks like this- `a,1
b,2
c,3`    but when i read it in, it calls it a dataframe and acts like 'a' and '1' are columns.....maybe my pandas needs to be updated? i installed it 2 months ago

Comment: Try passing index=False to to_csv() to create a single column csv file

Comment: very close, I have header=None and squeeze=True on the from_csv and I have index=False on the to_csv, it now shows that it is a series but it deleted my row of (a,b,c) because of index=False, I want index to be a,b,c etc and then it matches up with 1,2,3 in the next row

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a minimal working example of your problem?